# VIMRC not reflecting changes to tab spacing

Tags: vim

I'm looking to modify my vimrc file so that when I press tab it indents 2 spaces instead of 4.
Currently I am using [SPF13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc)

I have changed the following lines in my vimrc:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
```

into:

```
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
```

then restarted my vimrc by using `:so $MYVIMRC`.

When I reopen Vim and press tab it is still tabing 4 spaces instead of 2.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your `so` command. Try restarting Vim to see if the problem still persists.

Comment: I quit everything closed the terminal and the issue is still present. By your response I'll assume my code looks correct, and something is preventing my changes from taking hold.

Comment: Yeah it is correct. Try also `set softtabstop=2`, see if that works. You can also try `set expandtab`.

Comment: @robbrit `expandtab` is already set in SPF13, but yes, I agree, it should always be on.

Comment: just an old-schooler's plea: leave `tabstop` at 8.  Most everyone runs with `expandtab` for sufficient reason so it won't have any effect -- until it does, at which point acting as if ASCII-TAB tabstops were anywhere but every 8 is opening a nothing-good-comes-of-this can of worms.

Comment: Since I am writing primarily ruby, I wish to have each tab be 2 spaces. If I make `tabstop` 8, then tab button becomes essentially useless. Surely there is a way to have tab make 2 spaces without risking future doom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain why it happened the way it did, `softtabstop` determines how many spaces is inserted via the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. What is actually inserted is a mix of tab characters and space characters.

`tabstop` determines the number of spaces "occupied" by each tab character.

So when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Vim tries to insert a number of space equal to `softtabstop` using tab characters, then pad the rest with space characters.

Examples:

- `softtabstop` = 4; `tabstop` = 2; insert 2 tab characters.
- `softtabstop` = 2; `tabstop` = 2; insert 1 tab character.
- `softtabstop` = 6; `tabstop` = 4; insert 1 tab character and 2 space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thank you so much, as robbrit pointed out, I needed to change this 
from:

```
set softtabstop=4
```

to

```
set softtabstop=2
```